# Can't Import LXML Using Python and Cloud 9

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to run a simple script and pull some values out of a web page. However, I get the error 'Unable to import lxml'. This is the full script

```
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('http://awebpage.com')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
names = tree.xpath('someXPath')
print names
```

I did pip install lxml and it says,

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

EDIT: I also did pip freeze just as another check to make sure it's installed.

Comment: do you get an error if you run python in a terminal and import lxml in there?

What is the full error you're seeing? and how are you running the script? is it from the terminal or from the python runner? Do you have a shebang specifying the correct python version?